# Проблемы с не параллельным запуском тестов

Tags: c#, entity-framework, юнит-тесты, nunit

Стэк: c# + ef + mssql + nunit 
При написании тестов на хранимые процедуры столкнулся со следующей проблемой: 
Негативные кейсы. 1 тестовый метод = несколько тест-кейсов. 
В процедуру передаются невалидные значения, затем проверяется текст возвращаемой ошибки, с ожидаемым текстом. 
Если запускать каждый тест по отдельности, то есть => класс с негативными кейсами => пишем тестовый метод, указываем данные в кейсах => запускаем, то все работает как надо. 
Если запускать несколько тестов сразу, то текст возвращаемой ошибки от первых процедур = тексту возвращаемой ошибки последней процедуры. 
Например:

1 тест - ожидаемый результат: 1 != 2 
2 тест - ожидаемый результат: 4 != 5

Если запустить эти тесты вместе, то 1 тест упадет и в стэк трэйсе будет написано: 
expected: 1 != 2 
but was: 4 !=5

То есть при запуске всех тестов сразу, тесты возвращают значение последнего теста либо значение какого-то конкретного теста из этого же класса с негативными кейсами.

В общем тестовом классе, от которого наследуются позитив/негатив классы указано [NonParallelizable]. Тестовые методы асинхронные. Если убрать [NonParalleblizable] ситуация та же самая.

Как быть, как можно подправить

Comment: у вас вопросы по коду, но вы не показываете код. Мы не знаем, как вы пишете ваши тесты, но если это unit тесты, то они должны быть независимы друг от друга.

Comment: `При написании тестов на хранимые процедуры` вероятно у вас одни тесты влияют на другие.